# In the /tools interface, can I see stats etc. only for certain tags?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I've started to look at the /tools interface (probably something I should have started doing about 10k ago), and found it not all that interesting. Most of the questions that bubble to the top are for extremely popular topics (Java, C++, etc). I am much more interested in reviewing extreme questions involving my particular area of expertise (I stay pretty rigidly within the [sql-server-*] tags). Is there a way to customize the data that is shown on these pages? I don't think I would provide very good input or make very good decisions on questions / answers / etc. outside of my area.

Comment: +1, this sounds like a very practical idea.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know to look for a 10k-tools tag here... seems a lot of folks use 10k and mod interchangeably. I've learned something. Thanks.

Comment: I see an image of a Chimp with a gun in your future.

Comment: @ConradFrix we should put the tag in the title and see waht happens

Comment: For close votes, you can do a limited version of this in the /review page, which lets you filter on individual tags. I agree, though, that it would be really useful to track at a glance close / delete / extreme votes in specific areas.